# Build process in Github Actions completed with exit code 2. -- AWS S3 sync

Tags: amazon-s3, github-actions

The following GitHub actions return an error code 2.  The last 3 lines from the Workflow seem to show the **aws sync** has completed successfully.  The **aws s3 sync** CLI command works correctly locally.

Worflow results:

```
609 Completed 52.0 MiB/52.0 MiB (5.9 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
610 upload: services/v1/myfile.py to s3://bucket/dev/backend/services/v1/myfile.py
611 Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

GitHub Action:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ap-southeast-2
    - name: Deploy to S3 bucket
      run: aws s3 sync . s3://bucket/dev/backend --exclude 'venv/*' --exclude '.aws-sam/*' --exclude '.git/*' --exclude '.gitignore'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK the answer is the AWS CLI (for s3 sync) is returning 2.  To check this I ran the following locally:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.30 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/20.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off

aws s3 sync . s3://bucket/dev/backend --exclude 'venv/*' --exclude '.aws-sam/*' --exclude '.git/*' --exclude '.gitignore'  --exclude 'services/ts_service1/.aws-sam/*' --profile ABC123 --delete

echo $?
2
```

And then checked the following:

```
aws s3 ls
echo $?
0
```

So there is something going on with the AWS CLI, both AWS CLI commands executed correctly.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html